# Jquery children select

Tags: jquery

How do I select the button with class `btnOk` inside of the `generic-modal-footer`?
Thanks in advance.

```
 $('#generic-modal-footer > .btnOk').click(function () {
    alert('cheguei');
    $('#genericModal').modal('hide');
});

 <div class="modal-footer" id="generic-modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnOk" id="generic-modal-button"></button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your existing code works just fine (https://jsfiddle.net/8jb7v1qu/) so either your actual HTML doesnt look like that, or your code doesnt

Comment: Why you can't use directly the button id attribute?

Comment: because i try to do a generic modal, wo recibes a class and the text of the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `.find()` method:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('#generic-modal-footer').find('.btnOk').click(function () {
    alert('cheguei'); 
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-footer" id="generic-modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnOk" id="generic-modal-button">Click me</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: WIth the find also doesn't work. I don't why doesn't work, the firebug doesn't show any error

Comment: down voters mentions reason first then click on down vote

Answer (score 0):

I try te on() function and works, thanks for the answers

```
    $('#generic-modal-footer').on('click','.btnOk', function () {
        alert('cheguei');
        $('#genericModal').modal('hide');
    });
```